# how to copy database structure from the model database to a new database?

Tags: orientdb

We are designing a SaaS system in a way of one database per tenant. When a new tenant signs up, a new database is created and the database structure(**schemes, hooks, functions and system data**) need to be setup.

Now, two solutions come to my mind: copying/replicating from the model DB to the new DB or setup the new DB based on SQL scripts. I'm fresh to OrientDB, so I valued any of your advice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you these options:

1. Create the first database (I used the following `OSQL` script):

   ```
   connect remote:localhost/BatchTest root root

   CREATE CLASS Customer EXTENDS V
   CREATE PROPERTY Customer.customerID INTEGER
   CREATE PROPERTY Customer.State STRING

   CREATE CLASS Store EXTENDS V
   CREATE PROPERTY Store.storeID INTEGER
   CREATE PROPERTY Store.State STRING
   CREATE PROPERTY Store.Zip INTEGER

   CREATE CLASS transaction EXTENDS E
   CREATE PROPERTY transaction.amt DOUBLE
   CREATE PROPERTY transaction.storeID INTEGER
   CREATE PROPERTY transaction.customerID INTEGER
   ```

   **Dataset**:

   ```
   orientdb {db=BatchTest}> select from v

   ----+-----+--------+----------+-----+---------------+-------+----+--------------
   #   |@RID |@CLASS  |customerID|State|out_transaction|storeID|Zip |in_transaction
   ----+-----+--------+----------+-----+---------------+-------+----+--------------
   0   |#12:0|Customer|1         |NY   |[size=4]       |null   |null|null
   1   |#12:1|Customer|2         |NJ   |[size=2]       |null   |null|null
   2   |#12:2|Customer|3         |PA   |[size=2]       |null   |null|null
   3   |#12:3|Customer|4         |NY   |[size=4]       |null   |null|null
   4   |#12:4|Customer|5         |NY   |[size=2]       |null   |null|null
   5   |#13:0|Store   |null      |NY   |null           |1      |1   |[size=4]
   6   |#13:1|Store   |null      |NJ   |null           |2      |3   |[size=6]
   7   |#13:2|Store   |null      |NY   |null           |3      |2   |[size=4]
   ----+-----+--------+----------+-----+---------------+-------+----+--------------
   ```

   **Classes/records**:

   ```
   orientdb {db=BatchTest}> list classes


   CLASSES
   ----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
    NAME                                         | SUPERCLASS                         | CLUSTERS   | RECORDS        |
   ----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
    _studio                                      |                                    | 11         |              1 |
    Customer                                     | [V]                                | 12         |              5 |
    E                                            |                                    | 10         |              0 |
    OFunction                                    |                                    | 6          |              0 |
    OIdentity                                    |                                    | -          |              0 |
    ORestricted                                  |                                    | -          |              0 |
    ORIDs                                        |                                    | 8          |              0 |
    ORole                                        | [OIdentity]                        | 4          |              3 |
    OSchedule                                    |                                    | 7          |              0 |
    OTriggered                                   |                                    | -          |              0 |
    OUser                                        | [OIdentity]                        | 5          |              3 |
    Store                                        | [V]                                | 13         |              3 |
    transaction                                  | [E]                                | 14         |             14 |
    V                                            |                                    | 9          |              0 |
   ----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
    TOTAL = 14                                                                                                   29 |
   ----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
   ```

Now to copy only the structure without dataset you can:

- Create some new empty databases (per user, group,...) and execute the `OSQL` script on each database to create only classes/properties;
- Export the database without dataset.

If you choose the second case, you can use the `EXPORT` and `IMPORT` commands with relative parameters.

1. Connect to the database to export the structure without records (`-includeRecords=false`):

   ```
   orientdb {db=BatchTest}> export database C:/export/destination/path/exportTest.gz -includeRecords=false
   Exporting current database to: database C:/export/destination/path/exportTest.gz -includeRecords=false in GZipped JSON format ...

   Started export of database 'BatchTest' to C:/destination/path/exportTest.gz...
   Exporting database info...OK
   Exporting clusters...OK (15 clusters)
   Exporting schema...OK (14 classes)
   Exporting index info...
   - Index OUser.name...OK
   - Index dictionary...OK
   - Index ORole.name...OK
   OK (3 indexes)
   Exporting manual indexes content...
   - Exporting index dictionary ...OK (entries=0)
   OK (1 manual indexes)

   Database export completed in 55ms
   ```
2. Create a new empty database:

   ```
   orientdb> create database remote:localhost/importTest root root plocal

   Creating database [remote:localhost/importTest] using the storage type [plocal]...
   Connecting to database [remote:localhost/importTest] with user 'admin'...OK
   Database created successfully.

   Current database is: remote:localhost/importTest
   ```
3. Import the structure exported:

   ```
   orientdb {db=importTest}> import database C:/path/to/exportTest.gz

   Importing database database C:/path/to/exportTest.gz...
   Started import of database 'remote:localhost/importTest' from C:/path/to/exportTest.gz...
   Non merge mode (-merge=false): removing all default non security classes
   - Class E was removed.
   - Class V was removed.
   - Class ORestricted was removed.
   - Class OTriggered was removed.
   - Class OSchedule was removed.
   - Class ORIDs was removed.
   - Class OFunction was removed.
   Removed 7 classes.
   Importing database info...OK
   Importing clusters...
   - Creating cluster 'internal'...OK, assigned id=0
   - Creating cluster 'default'...OK, assigned id=3
   - Creating cluster 'orole'...OK, assigned id=4
   - Creating cluster 'ouser'...OK, assigned id=5
   - Creating cluster 'ofunction'...OK, assigned id=6
   - Creating cluster 'oschedule'...OK, assigned id=7
   - Creating cluster 'orids'...OK, assigned id=8
   - Creating cluster 'v'...OK, assigned id=9
   - Creating cluster 'e'...OK, assigned id=10
   - Creating cluster '_studio'...OK, assigned id=11
   - Creating cluster 'customer'...OK, assigned id=12
   - Creating cluster 'store'...OK, assigned id=13
   - Creating cluster 'transaction'...OK, assigned id=14
   Rebuilding indexes of truncated clusters ...
   Done 2 indexes were rebuilt.
   Done. Imported 13 clusters
   Importing database schema...OK (14 classes)

   Importing indexes ...
   - Index 'OUser.name'...OK
   - Index 'dictionary'...OK
   - Index 'ORole.name'...OK
   Done. Created 3 indexes.
   Importing manual index entries...
   - Index 'dictionary'...OK (0 entries)
   Done. Imported 1 indexes.
   Rebuild of stale indexes...
   Stale indexes were rebuilt...
   Deleting RID Mapping table...OK


   Database import completed in 7501 ms

   orientdb {db=importTest}> list classes
   ```

   **Structure:**

   ```
   CLASSES
   ----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
    NAME                                         | SUPERCLASS                         | CLUSTERS   | RECORDS        |
   ----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
    _studio                                      |                                    | 11         |              0 |
    Customer                                     | [V]                                | 12         |              0 |
    E                                            |                                    | 10         |              0 |
    OFunction                                    |                                    | 6          |              0 |
    OIdentity                                    |                                    | -          |              0 |
    ORestricted                                  |                                    | -          |              0 |
    ORIDs                                        |                                    | 8          |              0 |
    ORole                                        | [OIdentity]                        | 4          |              0 |
    OSchedule                                    |                                    | 7          |              0 |
    OTriggered                                   |                                    | -          |              0 |
    OUser                                        | [OIdentity]                        | 5          |              0 |
    Store                                        | [V]                                | 13         |              0 |
    transaction                                  | [E]                                | 14         |              0 |
    V                                            |                                    | 9          |              0 |
   ----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
    TOTAL = 14                                                                                                    0 |
   ----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
   ```

   **Dataset:**

   ```
   orientdb {db=importTest}> select from v


   0 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.004 sec(s).
   ```
4. You can customize the exported database with a lot of parameters ([official OrientDB documentation](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Console-Command-Export.html)).

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi @LucaS. Thanks.     If the DB copying must be done automatically at run-time( while the new user sign-ups online), I have to choose CASE 1--"OSQL script".     Do you mean that?        You know, we do not want to do that offline and manually for each new user, which causes bad UE and huge cost.